# angularJS Order By key list

Tags: angularjs

How I can achieve ORDER BY either in ascending or descending mainSubjectAllocationList & optionSubjectAllocationList KEY while printing table.

My code is as below

```
vm.sectionListWithClass = [

  {
    "classStd": "Prep-2015",
    "classId": "1",
    "section": "B",
    "sectionName": "RED",
    "sectionId": "6",
    "mainSubjectAllocationList": "Hindi, Biology, Geography, English, Chemistry",
    "mainSubjectAllocationId": "28",
    "optionSubjectAllocationList": "Chemistry, P.T, 3rd lang Urdu, Art, 3rd lang Arabic, 3rd lang Chinese, 3rd lang German, Life Skill",
    "optionSubjectAllocationId": "27"
  }
 ]





 <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.sectionListWithClass | groupBy: 'classStd'" >
                    <tr ng-repeat="player in value | orderBy: 'section' | orderBy:'mainSubjectAllocationList':true">
```

Comment: What's the result of the code above ?

Comment: its doing order on section only not on both section and mainSubjectAllocationList. Alternate I change my SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested yet, but I'm quite confident):

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in value | orderBy: ['section', '-mainSubjectAllocationList']">
```